# Listados de empleados con y sin trabajo

Tags: php, base-de-datos, mysqli, lista, condiciones

Me gustaría saber si alguien me puede ayudar con un problema que tengo, resulta que tengo un formulario que el empleado tiene que cargar una novedad, eso todo bien, se hace la carga, pero lo que necesito es mostrar un listado de todos los empleados que hicieron la carga y los que no hicieron,
Para eso tengo 3 tablas: ÁREA, EMPLEADOS, NOVEDAD.

Hasta aquí puedo unir los empleados y el área, pero no puedo traer la novedad que cargo.

```
$base = "SELECT empleados.id, empleados.nombre, empleados.id_area, area.nombrearea
    FROM empleados
    INNER JOIN area ON empleados.id_area=area.id";
$nquery = mysqli_query($conn, $base);
```

Si pongo así trae todos como se tuvieran cargado novedad

```
$base = "SELECT empleados.id, empleados.nombre, empleados.id_area, area.nombrearea, novedad.licencia1
    FROM empleados
    INNER JOIN area ON empleados.id_area=area.id
    INNER JOIN novedad";
$nquery = mysqli_query($conn, $base);
```

¿Alquien me puede ayudar? Ya se me quemaron los libros.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! falta la condicion de join con novedad.. si no, esta haciendo un producto cartesiano...

Comment: Lee [este artículo](https://programacionymas.com/blog/como-funciona-inner-left-right-full-join) para aclarar tus dudas sobre _JOIN_ y, seguramente, verás que debes usar `LEFT JOIN novedad`, además de agregar la condición `ON empleados.id = novedad.id_empleado` o el nombre de campo que corresponda.

Comment: Disculpen mi ignorancia, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a utilizar `LEFT JOIN`. Se utiliza para mostrar todos los resultados a la izquierda del join y, en caso de no tener resultados, mostrará `NULL` (no conozco la estructura de las tablas, pero revisalo y cámbialo acorde con la estructura):

```
$base = "SELECT empleados.id, empleados.nombre, empleados.id_area, area.nombrearea, novedad.licencia1
    FROM empleados
    INNER JOIN area ON empleados.id_area=area.id
    LEFT JOIN novedad ON empleados.id=novedad.id_empleado";
$nquery = mysqli_query($conn, $base);
```